# Parse Crash Reporting - Script Does not End

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I just enabled ParseCrashReporting in my app, and now when I build the app, Xcode stays on "Running 2 of 2 custom shell scripts" (i have another simple script for HockeyApp integration, placing it before that does not change anything).

My script is below:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
cd ~/OneDrive/AppName

parse symbols AppName -p "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

My AppName folder is also where I started my parse cloud repo, it contains the folders cloud, config and public. I tried changing the path to AppName/cloud but no change.

Xcode stays running that script for a long time...i've waited 10 minutes for it before and it doesn't continue beyond that. Once I stop the build, I get an error: `Shell script invocation error`:

```
Uploading iOS symbol files...
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I assume the error just shows because I cancel the task. Why would this be sticking like so? I have looked at several questions on parse crash reporting and have not seen any similar issues.

Comment: The chances are your parse command line is trying to update itself. This never works for me. Download the latest parse command line and install it manually

Comment: already using latest cli version 2.2.0

Comment: the script seems to finish in 5 - 10 minutes...every time I build/run my project is this normal? I can't accept that if it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the following script instead, I just tested it and it works:

```
echo "Parse Crash Reporting"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
CLOUD_CODE_DIR=${PROJECT_DIR}/helloKittyAdventureTimeCloudCodeFolder

if [ -d ${CLOUD_CODE_DIR} ]; then
cd ${CLOUD_CODE_DIR}
parse symbols YOUR_PARSE_APP_NAME --path="${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
echo "Finished uploading symbol"
else
echo "Unable to upload symbols"
fi
```

IMPORTANT:

The following line needs to be changed based on your folder name, that's it, keep everything else the same:

```
CLOUD_CODE_DIR=${PROJECT_DIR}/helloKittyAdventureTimeCloudCodeFolder <===this should be the 
name or your own folder!!, so, if your folder is named theAdventuresOfCaptainCookCloudCode, 
then you would type this:

CLOUD_CODE_DIR=${PROJECT_DIR}/theAdventuresOfCaptainCookCloudCode
```

Also, one more thing to note, you don't need the echos and such if your run this as a Run Script in Xcode, but you don't have to take them out either, you can just run it like this and you won't have a build error.

One more thing, make sure to change YOUR_PARSE_APP_NAME to the name or your app, sorry about that, this also needs to be changed

Comment: It still just basically freezes on "Running custom shell script". No error is generated until I cancel it. By the way, all I have in my "cloud code" folder is main.js with the default hello world function. In the docs it didn't say anything about adding to it? Is that script supposed to take a long time to run?

Comment: yep, your cloud code folder should be in the same folder as your xcode.project folder and then your cloud code folder should contain the following sub folders: cloud ... config ... public

Comment: After letting Xcode build the app for about 10 minutes I get this error: Parse `Crash Reporting
Uploading iOS symbol files...
read tcp 54.164.220.140:443: connection reset by peer
Finished uploading symbol
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure`

Comment: 10 minutes!! wow, that's either a huge freaking app with a ton of symbol files or you have what looks like a slow internet connection, keep trying it and see what happens, that's the best bet for now

Comment: I have a very fast connection and the app is very small. Very frustrating.

Comment: I used speedtest.net and while I have 20mbps down, barely 0.3mbps up...sounds like thats my issue.

Comment: wow, that's totally weird, let me check on a few other things, I think i may have a solution